# How to keep only string(s) that start with "bs"?

Tags: php, regex

I have this array

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'Â bs-0468R(20UG)' (length=16)
  1 => string 'Â bs-1338R(1ML)' (length=15)
  2 => string 'Â bs-1557G(NO BSA)' (length=18)
  3 => string 'Â bs-3295R(NO BSA)' (length=18)
  4 => string '" bs-0730R' (length=10)
  5 => string '" bs-3889R' (length=10)
  6 => string 'bs-0919R (NO BSA)' (length=17)
```

I want to throw away everything and only keep the string that start with `bs`.

What is the best of doing it ?

Comment: So here you only want the last element or the last 3?

Comment: I want to keep only the element that start with "bs". I don't get your question - sorry.

Comment: index 4 and 5 start with `" bs` not `bs` which I believe is @Rizier123's question.

Comment: I think @AbraCadaver got it, but if you have a better solution feel free to post your.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function ($i) {
    return strpos($i, 'bs')===0;
});
```

Comment: Kids, I know regular expressions are "cool", but `strpos()` is efficient and you should use it whenever possible.

Comment: May I ask why do you use `=== 0` ?

Comment: @uml-14 To check that "bs" is at the start position 0

Comment: strpos() returns the position of the substring, if found. 0 position would be the very beginning of the string.
http://php.net/strpos

Comment: @Sammitch: I don't know if this way is faster, because `array_filter` isn't particulary fast.

Comment: @uml-14: as said Rizier & BlahArgh, `strpos` returns the position in the string, but when the string is not found it returns `false`, the problem is that PHP isn't strongly typed, and that `false==0`  is a true condition, so to check the type too you must use the  strict comparison operator `===`. *(The callback function in `array_filter` is supposed to return a boolean)*

Comment: Why would it not be fast? All it does is iterate over the array.

Comment: @Sammitch: `array_filter` is well know to be slow (I can't explain why, I haven't looked at the source code), but with a small array like this you will see that the `preg_grep` way is two times faster *(more with a bigger array)*. The advantages of `preg_grep` against the `array_filter` way are: 1) you don't have the cost of a callback function, 2) you use an anchored pattern *(so it doesn't have to parse all the string)*. Without regex, you can use a simple `foreach` to do the same thing, it is faster than `array_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

I love `preg_grep`:

```
$result = preg_grep('/^bs/', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Casimir et Hippolyte. If you know you're always going to have a controlled dataset such as your example (rare), you can always just reference the string as an array -- which it already is under the hood:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function ($v) {
    return $v[0] . $v[1] == 'bs';
});
```

Regex is amazing and not a performance problem for *most* situations, however I have had some issues with it where other functionalities were far faster and efficient when it counted. I understand that statement is not true for the majority of applications, but it is worth noting.